# H5P content error - on trying to edit in Moodle

Tags: moodle, h5p

In Moodle, I created a new H5P "activity", and then uploaded a reusable template of the crossword from the H5P site. On trying to open the settings and EDIT the content of this crossword (and also the essay writing feature), I got the following error:

```
**The given URL is incorrect or you cannot edit this file.
More information about this error**
```

Following the link gave the following error on the moodle forums:

```
error/core h5p/error:emptycontentid
```

It has worked in the past and works with certain H5P content types, so I am unsure as to why this edit error is occurring. I've posted on Moodle/H5P forums which aren't terribly active so hoping for some answers here!

Comment: What do you mean by the H5P forum is not too active? You got an answer within one hour (https://h5p.org/comment/47495#comment-47495) telling you that this is an error message from moodle's custom H5P integration and you'd better ask on the moodle forums for better chances for an answer - some moodle devs browse the forums, too. But you don't seem to have done that (https://moodle.org/mod/forum/view.php?id=8603).

Answer (score 0):

It may seem silly, but took me a while to figure it out. I had simply uploaded the same file and it doesn't allow the same file name. This was what was causing the error.